# There is no way to make Windows recognize my Pro Controller (NSwitch Controller) via USB

Tags: windows-10, usb, steam, game-controller

I have been trying to use my Nintendo Switch Pro Controller in my PC but it only is able to use it in Steam which it have no problems and works perfectly.

But if I try to use in any other game or, just try to see if windows recognize it just doesn't work.

It's like Windows knows that is connected but doesn't trigger any button.

I have connected via USB due to I have no Bluetooth. I have tried a lot of external programs but still doesn't work.

What could I do? What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hardware solution is the
[8BitDo Wireless USB Adapter](https://www.8bitdo.com/wireless-usb-adapter/)
($20) which is a Bluetooth adapter via USB port that emulates an Xbox 360 gamepad
which most PC games can easily work with.

Software solutions are more complicated, because they usually need fiddling
for each game and will not work for some games.

Some alternatives (which I never tried):

- [BetterJoyForCemu](https://github.com/Davidobot/BetterJoyForCemu),
  free and open-source, described in this
  [REDIT post](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/9cu0ev/pro_controller_joycon_driver_for_windows_10/).
- [reWASD](https://www.rewasd.com/nintendo-switch-pro-controller-on-pc)
  free and open-source.
- [x360ce](http://www.x360ce.com/)
  free and open-source, described in this
  [PC Gamer article](https://www.pcgamer.com/how-to-use-a-nintendo-switch-pro-controller-on-pc/).

Comment: I tried both 3 software solutions with a Pro Controller knockoff, and reWASD was the only one to work.